# Need to find if an international flight 2 months ago was cancelled

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, refunds, lufthansa

My parents were scheduled on UA8784 from IAD to MUC on July, 24 2020 22:30 and were told it was cancelled due to covid several days beforehand. They were refunded.  We were on the same flight but as the Lufthansa partner LH415 IAD (Dulles) to MUC (Munich) July, 24 2020  22:30 and we called to cancel since we already knew the flight would not take off when my parents told us.  Now we are told by Lufthansa that we cannot get refunded because we were the ones to cancel and that the flight was on time.  How can this be true?  The online historic flight data seems to only go back a few days.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a flight rights expert, but I think it's possible you forfeited the refund by cancelling yourself instead of waiting for Lufthansa to cancel, meaning it doesn't matter any more if the flight actually took place or not.

Comment: I tried flightstats and flightaware but they only go back a few days

Comment: @Jake There isn't a single source for FLIFO. It's aggregated from airlines and navigation companies and airport operators, and the aggregator is doing so in order to sell it to consultancies, agencies, and the like. If you want more than a few days of history, you can purchase a subscription to the service.

Comment: This may be something of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com); as @Sabine notes, if you proactively canceled your flight, you probably won't be entitled to a refund, regardless of whether it operated, depending on the original fare rules. If you had waited for the airline to announce that they had canceled the flight, you would unambiguously have been entitled to a refund. Lufthansa also has a COVID waiver allowing you to postpone your departure through December 2021, so you also could have rescheduled without penalty.

Comment: @Jake Most such sites have options to access longer history if you pay. IIRC Flightradar24 has a free trial option that allows you to go back a year.